# Name Multiple Ranges - Using Data in Two Columns

Tags: excel, vba, range

I searched for this with no luck. Any help is appreciated.

#### Data Set

I have a fairly tall dataset (roughly between 1,000 and 5,000 rows) with two columns; one for category and the other for values. The data varies; there might be 10 categories, maybe 100, or any other number:

| Column A | Column B |
| --- | --- |
| Category 1 | Value 1 |
| Category 1 | Value 2 |
| Category 1 | Value 3 |
| Category 2 | Value 4 |
| Category 2 | Value 5 |
| Category 2 | Value 6 |
| Category 3 | Value 7 |
| Category 3 | Value 8 |
| Category 3 | Value 9 |
| Category 3 | Value 10 |

etc.

#### Objective

I would like to create ranges based on the values in Column A that only include the values in Column B, using the value of Column A as the name of the range.

So for example:

- Range Name = "Category 1" ; Range Values { Value 1, Value 2, Value 3}
- Range Name = "Category 2" ; Range Values { Value 4, Value 5, Value 6}
- Range Name = "Category 3" ; Range Values { Value 7, Value 8, Value 9,
  Value 10}
- etc.

#### Things Attempted

I've tried a number of things, but I'm such a VBA novice that I can't tell what is an effective way to approach this solution and fear I keep making wrong turns in the approach.

I thought perhaps trying to find the next distinct value in Column A might be a good idea paired with the offset function, but I can't get much further than simply creating and naming the range of categories to look through in Column A. I'm sure this isn't necessary, but I am definitely not a VBA expert.

```
Sub AllCategories

Dim sht As Worksheet  
Dim lrow As Long  
Dim r As Range  

Set sht = Sheets("Sheet1")  
lrow = sht.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row  
Set r = sht.Range("A2:A" & lrow)  

ActiveWorkbook.Names.Add _  
   Name:="AllCategories", _  
   RefersTo:=r  

End Sub
```

#### Ideas?

It seems like I'll need a start variable and end variable for the categories, but I can't find how to look for the next distinct value. Maybe some Find variable function that loops?

Thanks for any help, it is much appreciated.

Cheers,
Prophet

Comment: It feels like named ranges may not be the most usable solution to whatever it is you're trying to do.  What's the step after getting all the named ranges - it might be worth looking for something where you don't need to set all of those up?

Comment: Great question. This is part of a large workbook with a large number of pivot tables. The next step is to use the named ranges to easily bring in multiple values into a pivot table at once. In reality, Category 1 may have 30 or 100 values (or more). Instead of manually adding each field to a pivot table each time the workbook needs to be re-run, I wanted to simply pull in the named range into the pivot. I figure I could drag and drop 30 categories into pivots and refresh instead of manually adding thousands of values to these pivots.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per my comment, I'm not sure whether what you're doing is the best way of doing things, and since you can't have spaces in the names of named variables, if your categories are actually going to be words and some could have spaces, you're setting up a lot of heartache processing exceptions. That aside, if it's really what you need, you weren't that far off, but you can't keep track of the start and end of each range with one variable. The code below will do what you've asked for:

```
Sub name_ranges()
    Dim iRow As Integer
    Dim iStart As Integer
    Dim rang As Range
    
    iRow = 2
    iStart = 2
    
    With Worksheets("test")
        While .Cells(iRow, 1) <> ""
            iRow = iRow + 1
            If .Cells(iRow, 1) <> .Cells(iRow - 1, 1) Then
                Set rang = Intersect(Columns(2), Rows(iStart & ":" & iRow - 1))
                rang_name = Replace(.Cells(iRow - 1, 1), " ", "")
                ActiveWorkbook.Names.Add Name:=rang_name, RefersTo:="=test!" & rang.Address
                iStart = iRow
            End If
        Wend    
    End With
End Sub
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you, this worked perfectly.
You're right regarding heartache. The data sets I'm working with are not well designed and has already led me to much pain. Funny story, I thought your VBA wasn't working, but I eventually found out that I had some hyphens, commas, etc. in the Category column . Once I cleared out those special characters it worked perfectly.
Thanks again, this was awesome.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using defined names, you can simply use Excel's AutoFilter under Data >> AutoFilter to get the results as shown below. Then, you can use a VBA macro to automatically select the Category as shown in the last selection. In this example, Category 2 is selected. The VBA code to make the table illustration is:

Selection.AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="Category 2"

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You could set up the lists without VBA if you have O365.

```
D1 =UNIQUE(A1:A10)
E1 =TRANSPOSE(UNIQUE(FILTER($B$1:$B$10,$A$1:$A$10=D1)))
```

Copy E1 down.

Then if you still needed names you could run this.

```
Sub MakeNames()

    Dim rng As Range
    Dim newName As String

    For Each rng In Range("D1#")
        newName = Replace(rng.Value2, " ", "_")
        ActiveWorkbook.Names.Add Name:=newName, RefersTo:="=" & rng.Offset(0, 1).Address & "#"
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. I wish I had O365. I found a few additions to be promising including Unique. Cheers